# General solution of a system of ODEs where $A - \lambda I = 0$, for a given $\lambda$ of $A$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system of ODEs

$$
\begin{cases}
x' = -ax \\
y' = -ay \\
\end{cases}
\implies
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\ y'
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-a & 0 \\
0 & -a
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

its eigenvalue $\lambda = -a$, and substituting it to $(A - \lambda I)\mathbf{k} = \mathbf{0}$:

$$ (A - \lambda I)k = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-a - (-a) & 0 \\
0 & -a - (-a)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
k_1 \\ k_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
k_1 \\ k_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix} \ ,
$$

which implies that all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2 \ (\neq \mathbf{0})$ is an eigenvector of $\lambda = -a$.

How do I write its homogeneous solution? Is it just $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{k}e^{-at}$, where $\mathbf{k}$ is any vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$? But I believe there must be more terms since $\lambda$ is a repeated eigenvalue but I do not know what it could be.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'which implies all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is an eigenvector of $\lambda = -a$'. I read it as there are two associated eigenvectors in the eigenspace, $\{ (1, 0)^{T}, (0, 1)^{T} \}$, which you would expect from looking at the ODEs themselves.

Comment: Since any vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ make the equation true.

Comment: I understand now, though I'm not sure what you mean by 'there must be more terms because $\lambda$ is a repeated eigenvalue'. The general solution is as $\color{red}{\text{you have written it}}$, and is the same as $\color{blue}{\text{my solution}}$ $$\boldsymbol{v}=\color{red}{(k_{1},k_{2})^{T}e^{-at}}=\color{blue}{k_{1}(1,0)^{T}e^{-at}+k_{2}(0,1)^{T}e^{-at}}$$ The specific values of $k_{1},k_{2}$ are picked out by the initial conditions for the ODEs at time $t = t^{*}$ $$\boldsymbol{v}(t^{*}) = (k_{1},k_{2})^{T} e^{-at^{*}} = (x_{0}, y_{0}) \implies (k_{1},k_{2}) = (x_{0}, y_{0})e^{at^{*}}$$

Comment: @mattos I see, thanks.